# CSS Positioning Margin Trouble

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am unsure how to position elements using css, as when I use methods like the following, whenever I resize the browser, the elements stay in the same place instead of where I would like them to be on the resized document. Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong?!

```
.logo {
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

#header h1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    color:  rgb(127, 127, 126);
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Please, have a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hHGRc/

Comment: Into roughly the same place as they were in the full-size document.

Comment: @XcodeDev: Perhaps you should be using `%` rather than `px`?

Comment: @XcodeDev - Why don't you post your actual CSS and markup someplace so people can take a look?  Try jsFiddle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within the (X)HTML DOM, CSS recognizes four types of positioning. By default, every element in HTML is positioned Statically. This means that it is positioned according to the place that it appears in the normal flow.

**Relative Positioning**
When an object is positioned `relative`, it means that it modifies the position based on the origin, which is where it would have been positioned in the normal flow (static). Relative also does something else special, however, and tells the browser that all of its children will be positioned according to this element, whether using relative or absolute.

**Absolute Positioning**
When an object is positioned `absolute`, it is placed according to the position of its nearest non-`static` positioned ancestor. If there is not one, then it uses the `<body>` to determine its position. This has the potential to break document flow, if its siblings or ancestors are not positioned `absolute`. If all are positioned `absolute` from the outer most top node to current node, then it will maintain the flow.

**Fixed Positioning**
This takes the element out of the flow and positions the object according to the Window object. This means that no matter the scroll state of the document, its size or any other property, it will always appear in that location. (This is how you get objects that scroll with you).

**Multiple solutions to your issue**
First, as described by others, you may add `position:relative` to the `#header`. It will, like explained above, make your header the nearest non-`static` ancestor and will use it and the basis for determining position. This is probably not ideal for you because you are an admitted novice and this one `absolute` could easily break enough flow that you may struggle with sibling elements.

As an alternative, you may change the logo from `position:absolute` to `position:relative`. This will keep your logo in the flow, but move the logo according to where it appears naturally in your document flow. Chances are that unless you are using floats in your #header, this is probably the one you want, as it a) keeps flow, b) allows for use of child element `floats` without losing flow, c) achieves your ideal positioning, d) keeps inheritance from parent elements (when it is important).

Another choice is to change the `#header` to `position:absolute`. This may alter the way everything interacts, however, unless you change all of your parent and sibling elements to `position:absolute`. Additionally, you may lose access to ancestor defined widths and heights, as they are only inherited if they are in the same flow. This is the 2nd best situation for you as you can simply add the rule `body * { position:absolute; }` and all will remain in the flow with you. However, it neglects to really teach you the things you need to learn about positioning and will simply be a crutch.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic

Answer (score 0):

CSS positioning can be tricky to understand correctly, but once you do, you'll find it very useful.

Try this: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Basically, to position anything that needs to be locked to a parent or a container element, the parent or container element itself needs to be positioned as well (absolute, or relative, doesn't matter) this is called positioning context. If an absolutely positioned element cannot find a parent or container that is positioning itself, it will then use the `body as the positioning context.

So in your example, if i were to to guess without seeing your HTML and more of your CSS,

adding `position:relative` to `#header` would then allow `.logo` to position itself absolutely from the top left of the `#header` element.

Also important to remember that absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal flow of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Defining position: absolute in CSS takes the element in question out of the flow of the document.

Think of this as layers: the bottom most layer is the document (though not always, depending on z-index!), and the top most layer is your element which you have defined as absolutely positioned.

By setting position: absolute, you have told the browser that you will be responsible for positioning the element relative to the top left corner of the document (screen). Above, you have told the browser to position #logo 20px from the left and 20px from the top of the document. When you resize your browser viewport, that element will remain in that position.

I think what you want is to position your element within the document flow, without using absolute positioning. This can be achieved with a combination of floats, margins, and padding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with a wild guess and saying that your logo is inside the header division, but your header is positioned staticly. Therefore, your logo is not being positioned according to the header, but according to the document's window. So it will be going to a position that is 20px right and 20px down from the top left corner of the document in all instances.

Try setting `position: relative` on your `#header` element. This will keep the header in the same place as it would always appear, and the logo will use the header box to find it's left and top positions rather than the browser window.