# How to make nav and right block fixed, also keep the whole container is in center?

Tags: html, css

How to make `nav` and `right` block fixed, also keep the whole container `centre` center?
without using js
http://jsfiddle.net/zujg22st/9/

I know `position fixed` is fixed to browser not to parent, so it can't be simply using fixed in relative div like `position absolute`

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="nav">nav</div>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <!--..... a lot ->
    </div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.center {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav {
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.left, .right {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
    background-color: green;
}
.right {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed positioned div within a relative parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846161/fixed-positioned-div-within-a-relative-parent-div)

Comment: @aniskhan001 possible not duplicate.  I never asking to css fixed positioned div within a relative parent div.  in my demo the layout is just for understanding what i want.  and seems the answer is like below Skyler Jokiel answer. I can't understand is when you can't understanding my question and still give a incorrect answer, people give you downvote, then you just remove that, then you tagged this is duplicate? this is so weird

Comment: so now you are visiting my profile and downvoting all of my correct answers. Awesome! :)

Comment: ?? what are you talking about

Comment: nothing, forget it, peace..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what we're going to want to do here is separate the this into two parts. We'll create a header at the top of the page and a body with a fixed right div. The nav bar at the top we can make a fixed header like so:

CSS:

```
#header{
    position:relative;
    height:30px;
    width:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="nav">nav</div>
</div>
```

The body will look like:

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
        <div class="left-el">left-el</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    position:relative;
    height:30px;
    width:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.centerheader{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

.center {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.nav {
    position:fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.left, .right {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
    background-color: green;
}
.right {
    position:fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 40px;
}

.right {
    margin-left: 3px;
    position: fixed;
}

body{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As a side note I modified the underlying `body {margin: 0 auto;}`. In jsfiddle there's a margin around the body and it causes ugliness when you have a header.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8wd39mkx/1/)**

Comment: Thanks it seems like what i want!!  but have few question: 1.how to make space between left and right?  2. if the window size small than 400px the blue box will overlay the left.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did it quick. Here I optimized your #2 by throwing the right column back in. You can add a space now by modifying 'margin-left' in '.right{}'

Here is the new [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8wd39mkx/) and I'll update inline above.

Answer (score -1):

A child div **cannot be `fixed`** relative to it's parent. But here's what I've got so far. I think it will help you.

Set `position: fixed;` to the `.nav`. Add same amount of `margin-top` as `.nav`s height to both `.left` and `.right`. In this case it's `30px`. Then set `position: absolute;` the `.right` div.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/zujg22st/7/)**

Comment: Thanks for reply! I know div cannot be set `position fixed` in relative parent, because `position fixed` is to screen.

Comment: Did you tried the DEMO? I think it's close enough of what you want.