# Fixed div within relative div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been reading about `fixed` `div`'s within `relative` and `absolute` `div`'s here:

[Fix position of div with respect to another div](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/fix-position-of-div-with-respect-to-another-div/235752)

[Fixed positioned div within a relative parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846161/fixed-positioned-div-within-a-relative-parent-div)

[Fixed position but relative to container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794000/fixed-position-but-relative-to-container)

And many other but none can help me to achive a behavior I have seen in few pages (blogs). I can not remember one at the moment, but here are some images to explain

View 1[image: View 1] & View 2 [image: View 2]

After scrolling down, the contextual menu sticks to the side of the view and moves down with the scrolling until reach the end of the section in which it stops. If there is more content after it, you can keep scrolling down but the contextual menu no longer follow your view. The same going up, you reach the section, the contextual menu follows you up until the start of the section, then stops and you can keep scrolling up.

Is this posible with only HTML and CSS or do I need a plugin?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q8nsepr/1/) piece of code, perphaps incomplete. Forgot to mention, I'm doing this in Angular 6+ as a component, so I don't have full access to the `index.html` file with the `body` tag. The jsFiddle shows what I can work with.

Comment: Are you looking for `position: sticky` perhaps? Some reading: [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/), [Elad Shechter](https://medium.com/@elad/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46).

Comment: I have tried with `sticky`, no success thou. Thanks, I'll read it

Comment: I don't understand how `position:fixed` didn't solve your problem, Can you provide a working code snippet with what you have tried.

Comment: some implementation with `fixed` either disappear the contextual menu or fixed to the whole window, not the section.

Comment: Add your code here please. Without seeing it, you can use `position: sticky` on menu, however, you need to add `position: relative` to the `body` tag as well as the container your menu is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few things going on:

1. You can set `body { position: relative }` in your CSS
2. `position: sticky` needs a full height column to work. Because your `col-6` that was holding your menu was only as tall as it needed to be, it won't scroll.
3. I moved the `p-sticky` class to your column.
4. `sticky` also needs a `top` value to know where the element should stick to once it becomes sticky.

```
.p-sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}


/*some attemps*/

.p-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.p-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.p-sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
}

.p-fixed {
  position: fixed;
}


/* Standar CSS*/

.navbar {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-fixed {
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

.content-ex1 {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content-ex2 {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.menu {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  some navbar things
</div>
<div class="navbar nav-fixed">
  some navbar things
</div>
<div class="content-ex1"> Some content here</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 p-sticky">
      <div class="menu">menu or something</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 content-ex2"> Some content here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-ex1"> Some content here</div>
```

Here's the fiddle to play around with (which includes your bootstrap):
http://jsfiddle.net/w4mz9dte/

**Note:** you appear to be using an old version of BootStrap. You may want to update to the newest version. In that case, only a few things will change - namely, you move the `p-sticky` class to the menu.

Here's the newest version of BS 4.4: http://jsfiddle.net/kamr0bjw/

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
/*some attemps*/
.p-relative{
  position:relative;
}
.p-absolute{
  position:absolute;
}
.p-sticky{
  position:sticky;
  top: 60px;
}
.p-fixed{
  position:fixed;
}


/* Standar CSS*/
.navbar{
  background-color: blue;
  width:100%;
}

.nav-fixed{
  top: 0px;
  z-index:1;
  position:fixed;
}
.content-ex1{
  height:200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.content-ex2{
  height:500px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
.menu{
  height:50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar">
  some navbar things
</div>
<div class="navbar nav-fixed">
  some navbar things
</div>
<div class="content-ex1"> Some content here</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"> 
      <div class="menu p-sticky">menu or something</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 content-ex2"> Some content here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-ex1"> Some content here</div>
```

Comment: You, sir, are the best! thank you very much! This solved it. Now I can see that `col-6` whas the "problem".